# How to add a horizontal scroll for a table with multiple columns and right alignment?

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have added a div, set the overflow style and placed the table inside the div. The table has multiple columns. So the table width is bigger than its parent container (div). I can see the horizontal scrolling is being appeared when I set the left align property for the table. But, the horizontal scrolling is not appearing when I set the align property of the table to Right.

Is there anyway to fix it? My sample code is given below.

```css
    table, th, td {
        border: 1px solid black;
    }
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>
    Test Table
    </title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div style="overflow: auto;border: 1px solid red;width: 90%; margin-left: 5%;">
    <table align="right">
      <tr>
        <th>Month</th>
        <th>Savings</th>
        <th>Savings</th>
        <th>Savings</th>
        <th>Savings</th>
        <th>Savings</th>
        <th>Savings</th>
        <th>Savings</th>
        <th>Savings</th>
        <th>Savings</th>
        <th>Savings</th>
        <th>Savings</th>
        <th>Savings</th>
        <th>Savings</th>
        <th>Savings</th>
        <th>Savings</th>
        <th>Savings</th>
        <th>Savings</th>
        <th>Savings</th>
        <th>Savings</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>January</td>
        <td>January</td>
        <td>January</td>
        <td>January</td>
        <td>January</td>
        <td>January</td>
        <td>January</td>
        <td>January</td>
        <td>January</td>
        <td>January</td>
        <td>January</td>
        <td>January</td>
        <td>January</td>
        <td>January</td>
        <td>January</td>
        <td>January</td>
        <td>January</td>
        <td>January</td>
        <td>January</td>
        <td>$100</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>February</td>
        <td>January</td>
        <td>January</td>
        <td>January</td>
        <td>January</td>
        <td>January</td>
        <td>January</td>
        <td>January</td>
        <td>January</td>
        <td>January</td>
        <td>January</td>
        <td>January</td>
        <td>January</td>
        <td>January</td>
        <td>January</td>
        <td>January</td>
        <td>January</td>
        <td>January</td>
        <td>January</td>
        <td>$80</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you add in  `<div>` style `direction:rtl` it works (if this is your expected behaviour :) ) :

```css
table, th, td {
        border: 1px solid black;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>
    Test Table
    </title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div style="overflow: auto; direction: rtl; border: 1px solid red; width: 90%; margin-left: 5%;">
    <table align="right">
      <tr>
        <th>Month</th>
        <th>Savings</th>
        <th>Savings</th>
        <th>Savings</th>
        <th>Savings</th>
        <th>Savings</th>
        <th>Savings</th>
        <th>Savings</th>
        <th>Savings</th>
        <th>Savings</th>
        <th>Savings</th>
        <th>Savings</th>
        <th>Savings</th>
        <th>Savings</th>
        <th>Savings</th>
        <th>Savings</th>
        <th>Savings</th>
        <th>Savings</th>
        <th>Savings</th>
        <th>Savings</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>January</td>
        <td>January</td>
        <td>January</td>
        <td>January</td>
        <td>January</td>
        <td>January</td>
        <td>January</td>
        <td>January</td>
        <td>January</td>
        <td>January</td>
        <td>January</td>
        <td>January</td>
        <td>January</td>
        <td>January</td>
        <td>January</td>
        <td>January</td>
        <td>January</td>
        <td>January</td>
        <td>January</td>
        <td>$100</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>February</td>
        <td>January</td>
        <td>January</td>
        <td>January</td>
        <td>January</td>
        <td>January</td>
        <td>January</td>
        <td>January</td>
        <td>January</td>
        <td>January</td>
        <td>January</td>
        <td>January</td>
        <td>January</td>
        <td>January</td>
        <td>January</td>
        <td>January</td>
        <td>January</td>
        <td>January</td>
        <td>January</td>
        <td>$80</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```